# Python is updating array instead of index. How to solve?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was working on a problem, but there seems a problem. On debugging I found that in line 15, the program is updating complete matrix to -1. Whereas I have specified to update index `i`, `j`.

Attached below is code and example input. Thanks in advance.

```
n = int(input().strip())
for i in range(n):
    sa = input().strip()
    s.append(sa)
import queue
ar =[[-10]*n]*n
q = queue.Queue()
error = False
while not q.empty():
    i,j = q.get()
    try:
        if ar[i][j-1]==-10:
            ar[i][j-1]=1+ar[i][j]
            q.put([i,j-1])
    except:
        error =True
    try:
        if ar[i][j+1]==-10:
            ar[i][j+1]=1+ar[i][j]
            q.put([i,j+1])
    except:
        error =True
    try:
        if ar[i-1][j]==-10:
            ar[i-1][j]=1+ar[i][j]
            q.put([i-1,j])
    except:
        error =True
    try:
        if ar[i+1][j]==-10:
            ar[i+1][j]=1+ar[i][j]
            q.put([i+1,j])
            print('here')
    except:
        error =True
m = -1        
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        #m = max(ar[i][j],m)
        print(ar[i][j],end='')
    print('')
print(m)
```

Example input:

[image: Input Example]

Comment: Your problem is on the statement: `ar = [[-10]*n]*n` which create items reference to same instance of `[-10]*n`.  Try using `ar = [[-10]*n for i in range(n)]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked.